# повторить асинхронную функцию при ошибке

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность, electron

Есть модуль https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api
Есть Example Usage:

```
const login = require("facebook-chat-api");

// Create simple echo bot
login({email: "FB_EMAIL", password: "FB_PASSWORD"}, (err, api) => {
    if(err) return console.error(err);

    api.listen((err, message) => {
        api.sendMessage(message.body, message.threadID);
    });
});
```

Всё круто. Только вот в течении суток listen может прервать свою работу (из-за временной потери сети, например). Правильно ли я понимаю, что нет никакой возможности тупо перезапускать автоматом выполнение этого кода при вылете по ошибке без понимания в асинхронность, колбэки, промисы, промисификацию и так далее?

Comment: а при чём тут электрон?

Comment: ну я в electron упаковываю. не знаю может ли это иметь какое-то отношение к вопросу

Answer (score 0):

Возможно этот пример вам подойдет, с библиотекой "facebook-chat-api" не знаком. Нужно понять как прерывает работу api.listen, с какой ошибкой и после этого выполнить подключение снова *API_ERROR_DISCONNECT*.

```js
const login = require("facebook-chat-api");

const connect = (auth, callback) => login(auth, callback);
   
function startBot (auth) {
  const connectCallback = (err, api) => {
      if(err) return {
        console.error(err);     
      }
      stopListening = api.listen((err, message) => {
          if (err === API_ERROR_DISCONNECT) {
            // проверка на отключение вашего API
            // ?добавить задержку
            console.error(err);
            stopListening()
            connect(auth, connectCallback);
            return;
          }
          api.sendMessage(message.body, message.threadID);
      });
  }
  connect(auth, connectCallback);
}

//    ...create api...

startBot({ email: "FB_EMAIL", password: "FB_PASSWORD" });
```